# Kotlin - Override a function with Generic return type

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have an interface. I want to make the return type of one of the function in that interface as generic type. Depend on how it is going to override, the return type will determine. When I try below code, I get errors `Conflicting overloads:` . I am new to Kotlin.

```
interface Loader<T> {

     fun <T> doSomething(inputParams: Map<String, String> = emptyMap()): T?

     fun cancelSomething(inputParams: Map<String, String> = emptyMap())
}

class LoaderHandler<MutableMap<String, String>> (private val foo: Foo) : Loader<MutableMap<String, String>> {

    override fun doSomething(inputParams: Map<String, String>): MutableMap<String, String>? { 
        // some code goes here.
        return mapOf("x" to "y")
    }

    override fun cancelSomething (inputParams: Map<String, String>) {
        println("cancelSomething")
    }
```

How can I implement the doSomething(...) function with return type of Map.

Comment: Your code has a lot more errors than just "Conflicting overloads". I'm assuming those are just typos? Please [edit] them out.

Comment: @Sweeper  Do you know to resolve my problem?

Comment: Yes, but please double check your question again - your code doesn't just have the "Conflicting overloads" error that you mentioned.

Comment: @Sweeper  regardless the specific error I get, how can I implement the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `<T>` in

```
 fun <T> doSomething(inputParams: Map<String, String> = emptyMap()): T?
```

It is not doing what you think it is.

Additionally,

```
class LoaderHandler<MutableMap<String, String>> (private val foo: Foo) : Loader<MutableMap<String, String>> {
```

should be

```
class LoaderHandler(private val foo: Foo) : Loader<MutableMap<String, String>> {
```

Comment: Then I get the error in the LoaderHandler ´Class 'LoaderHandler' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member´. Also in the function I have error  ´Expecting member declaration´

Comment: It [works for me](https://pl.kotl.in/NBqNM6LQx).

Comment: Yes this works, Thanks alot. I had some issues in my IDEA